# Receiving POST data in .ashx file

Tags: asp.net, rest, http-post

I have implemented a generic handler to work as a restful web service in ASP.Net. I have a problem receiving the XML file that is being posted to this web service. I cannot actually see anything being passed. I have gone through the form, querystring, and file properties of the request object. Everything is empty. I know that the file has been posted correctly because I can see it while using a port sniffer.

How can I access this file?

Comment: you have tried accessing the Request.Files collection?

Comment: Yes i did. Files is for files that were posted using the file upload control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After hours of searching, of course I found the answer after posting my question here. I was able to access the file using a stream reader. The code looks like this.

```
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
    Dim xmlFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: C# syntact: `System.IO.StreamReader reader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream); string value = reader.ReadToEnd();`